# data.table only alter columns under certain conditions

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table where I want to change some columns under certain conditions.

```
tmp = data.table(id = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3), flag = c(NA, NA, 4, NA, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, 7, 5, 6))

> tmp
    id flag
 1:  A   NA
 2:  A   NA
 3:  A    4
 4:  B   NA
 5:  B    5
 6:  B    5
 7:  C   NA
 8:  C   NA
 9:  C   NA
10:  D    7
11:  D    5
12:  D    6
```

What I want is if all values in the flag column by id are NA, then I want the value to be 5, if only some are NA then I want the value to be the min, if none are NA I want the original values back.

I wrote a few ifelse statements to do this, but what I'm finding is that if there are no NAs in the flag, and I return flag by that value it will return the first value it sees.

```
tmp[ , "flag2" := ifelse(all(is.na(flag)), 5, ifelse(any(is.na(flag)), min(flag, na.rm = TRUE), flag)), by = .(id)]

> tmp
    id flag flag2
 1:  A   NA     4
 2:  A   NA     4
 3:  A    4     4
 4:  B   NA     5
 5:  B    5     5
 6:  B    5     5
 7:  C   NA     5
 8:  C   NA     5
 9:  C   NA     5
10:  D    7     7
11:  D    5     7
12:  D    6     7
```

Why is this not returning the original sequence of 7 5 6 for D? And, is there an easy way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any(...)` returns a single logical value instead of a logical vector, so the result takes the first element of `flag`, the same as:

```
ifelse(FALSE, 3, c(2,3))
# [1] 2
```

In your case, you don't need vectorized `ifelse`, `if/else` should work:

```
tmp[ , "flag2" := if(all(is.na(flag))) 5 else if(any(is.na(flag))) min(flag, na.rm = TRUE) else flag, by = .(id)]

tmp
#    id flag flag2
# 1:  A   NA     4
# 2:  A   NA     4
# 3:  A    4     4
# 4:  B   NA     4
# 5:  B    5     4
# 6:  B    4     4
# 7:  C   NA     5
# 8:  C   NA     5
# 9:  C   NA     5
#10:  D    7     7
#11:  D    5     5
#12:  D    6     6
```